# hadoop fs -mkdir not creating desired folders

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to execute the simple Hadoop Mapreduce Wordcount example. I am following this [guide](https://kishorer747.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/running-a-wordcount-mapreduce-example-in-hadoop-2-4-1-single-node-cluster-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit/) to run the program.

One of the steps is to create input and output folders on the hdfs file system.

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/input
```

But that gave me this error:

> DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
>   Instead use the hdfs command for it.
>
> 16/09/25 10:57:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable

So I tried :

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/input
```

Output:

> 16/09/25 10:59:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable

But the input folder has not been created.

What do I do? Please help!

Comment: Neither of those logs contain any errors. Do you have any other logs? What are you doing afterwards that makes you think the folder hasn't been created?

Comment: ls doesn't show the folders in `/usr/local/hadoop/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the folder *is* being created as neither of the logs you've posted indicate an error. I think you're just looking in the wrong place.

You should execute the command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /usr/local/hadoop/
```

and confirm that the `input` directory exists there.

You can't find this directory by using the normal Unix `ls` command.